# How to bind multiple Firebase query or FUITableViewDataSource to single UITableView in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Basically, need to query from a different level of Firebase data tree like below.
0--data00
|-1-data10
  |-data11
  |-2-dat20

child node can be data or next level node, so have to use one query path per level, but want to display and update all in one `tableview` as
data00
data10
data11
data20

so far I only find 1 query to 1 tableview binding

```
self.dataSource = self.tableView.bind(to: query) { tableView, indexPath, snapshot in
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)
/* populate cell */
return cell
}
```

I did try loop thru an array of query and bind, but only the last query data is displayed on the `tableview`

Answer (score 0):

FirebaseUI data sources only support a single source per view.

You could try to build this yourself using the code of the existing data sources as inspiration. It might be more feasible for your specific use-case than it has proven as a generic solution in FirebaseUI itself.

Comment: which specific adapter are you referring to? I did that on Android version FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, but not sure what is the one in IOS.

Comment: Sorry, I typed adapter out of habit there. On iOS, you'll want to look at `FUITableViewDataSource` or `FUICollectionViewDataSource`. Both lean heavily on `FUIArray`, which is a synchronized "array" backed by a Firebase reference or query.